# Serre Fibration long exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I want to know if there exists something like the long exact sequence 
on the following case:

Let $p : E\rightarrow B$ a continuous surjective map such that 
there exists an open dense subset $U$ of $B$ such that $p$ its a trivial bundle over $p^{-1}(U)$ (i mean that $p^{-1}(U)\cong U \times T$ for some topological space $T$ and $p$ acts as the projection on the first coordinate) . For some $b\in U$ there exists something like the Serre long exact sequence
associated to the maps $p^{-1} ( b ) \rightarrow E \rightarrow B$.

In particullary interested on the case when $E,B$ and $T$ are algebraic varieties and $P$ is a quotient for the action of a reductive algebraic group on $E$.